# JQuery - Copy Columns Within A Current Row

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery. I am working on a function that to copy/clone columns (TD) within a row (TR). Here is what I try to accomplish:

My HTML codes:

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" name="btnAdd" value="Add">
    </tr>

    <tr id="template">
        <td>
            <a href="#" onClick="$(this).removeRow();">Delete</a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <select id="ddlCol_1" name="ddlCol_1">
                <option value="">Select Option</option>
                <option value="A">A</option>
                <option value="B">B</option>
                <option value="C">C</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlOp_1" name="ddlOp_1">
                <option value="=">=</option>
                <option value=">">></option>
                <option value="<"><</option>
                <option value="">*</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="cond_1" name="cond_1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddlConjunction_1" name="ddlConjunction_1" onChange="checkORCondition(this);">
                <option value="And">And</option>
                <option value="Or">Or</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

The function checkORCondition(this) is called when a select "ddlConjunction_1" onChange.

```
function checkORCondition(e)
    {
        trid = e.id 
        alert("trid: " + trid); 
        $('#table').find("THE CURRENT TR"), The copy ONLY colmns 2-5 and append to the last TD .....    
    }
```

This above function would find the CURRENT row (TR), and then copy columns from 2-5, and append those copied columns (with elements) to the LAST column.

Please Help. Thank you,

Comment: Any help? If the above request is too hard. Please help with a sample code of how to copy/code a column (TD), and I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Never Mind, I figured it out!